# Internet Explorer 11 flexbox issues

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

The code I've written works in every browser I've tested except IE 11. The problem seems to be here:

```
#wrapper {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -o-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
}
```

If I remove flex, it becomes more manageable, but with them, it shrinks all the content into this long, narrow div that goes on forever.

Would it help if I tested in IE 10?

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issue or else we won't be able to help

Comment: @Michael_B If you post the relevant html and tag me when you have, I will do my best to help you out.

Comment: There is no need to use the browser-prefixes on flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding 100% width to the body fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6):

You just need flex:1; It will fix issue for the IE11

```
#wrapper {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -o-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-moz-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
-o-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 1em;
flex:1;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't work. I tried 'auto' too and that didn't change anything either.

Comment: Possibly add a screenshot?

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, and Edge:  http://postimg.org/image/rbsn4ft8l/

Internet Explorer: http://postimg.org/image/grbt7njdv/

Both blues are meant to be the same blue...

Comment: `flex: 1` you set on the children of a flex container, so if the `wrapper` is a _wrapper_ this won't change anything ... and since we can't see the markup, I don't understand how you possible could know this would solve it

Answer (score 1):

Try `display: run-in` or `display: inline-block` instead of `display: -ms-flexbox`;